# Xpath Expression - Select between two known Tags

Tags: html, xpath

Given the following HTML:

```
<body>
    <h2>
        <span class="mw-headline" id="KNOWNID">S</span>
        <span class="mw-editsection">
            <span class="mw-editsection-bracket">[</span>
            <a href="/w/index.php?title=Og&amp;action=edit&amp;section=4">Bn</a>
            <span class="mw-editsection-bracket">]</span>
        </span>
    </h2>
    <div class="h"></div>
    <p>M</p>
    <p>M</p>
    <p>M</p>
    <p>M</p>
    <p>M</p>
    <h2>
        <span class="mw-headline" id="NEXTKNOWNID">S</span>
        <span class="mw-editsection">
            <span class="mw-editsection-bracket">[</span>
            <a href="/w/index.php?title=Og&amp;action=edit&amp;section=4">Bn</a>
            <span class="mw-editsection-bracket">]</span>
        </span>
    </h2>
</body>
```

I have the `ID="KNOWNID`" and need to select all `<p></p>` Elements until the `id="NEXTKNOWNID"`. How can this be acomplised with XPATH?

Thanks

Comment: how to do this, means which language you prefer? in jquery, javascript, .net , java...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling`:

```
//p[preceding-sibling::h2/span[@id="KNOWNID"] and following-sibling::h2/span[@id="NEXTKNOWNID"]]
```